# Combining data from multiple columns in a table and geting a total

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to combine the following columns of data from one table and combine it into one column getting a count. The table is DebitTransactions and these are the columns (DiagnosisCode1, DiagnosisCode2, DiagnosisCode3, DiagnosisCode4, DiagnosisCode5, DiagnosisCode6, DiagnosisCode7, DiagnosisCode8, DiagnosisCode9, 
DiagnosisCode10, DiagnosisCode11, DiagnosisCode12. Can someone help?

This is what I have so far. Now I need to count. So for example combining all the columns I get something like this 724.2 724.2 724.2 =3

Select DiagnosisCode1 as DiagnosisCount
from DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode2 as DiagnosisCount
from DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode3 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode4 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode5 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode6 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode7 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode8 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode9 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode10 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions
Union all
Select DiagnosisCode11 as DiagnosisCount
From DebitTransactions

Comment: Add the columns together?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I figured it out thanks